# downgrade windows 10 pro to original edition

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-10-upgrade, downgrade

After upgrading to windows 10 pro on a tablet of mine that came preloaded with windows 10 home, I would like to downgrade it back to home. However, the tablet doesn't have a recovery partition and I don't have the licence key for home.. How can I simply revert back to the original windows edition I had? BTW I have tried the reset your PC thing.. needless to say, it didn't work

Comment: how much time has passed since upgrade? windows 10 keeps the previous system for 30 days in case you want to go back.

Comment: 2, maybe three days?

Comment: If there is some feature of Windows 10 Pro that you don't like, you may be able to uninstall that feature. Or are you looking for a refund of the upgrade?

Comment: Nope, I just want to go back to home edition.. I couldn't be bothered about, and probably wouldn't even get, a refund

Comment: The brand and model of tablet may help us answer your question.

Comment: Your license is embedded in firmware.  Download a Windows .ISO and install Windows 10 Home

Comment: As stated reinstalling should work. Or you can try "Advanced Reboot (shift + reboot) - Troubleshoot - Advanced Options - See more recovery options - Go back to previous build" to restore Win10 Home.

Answer (score 3):

As my last answer was irrelevant, I have changed it.

I found a site where you can download a tool to reinstall windows 10, and it has instructions. I will be posting them here, but with a few tweaks.

Since your license key is already in your firmware, just select the "home" version of windows 10 when reinstalling.

[Download Tool](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=691209)

**Follow these instructions to perform a clean installation of Windows 10.**

**Warning**

If you format a drive partition during installation, any data on the partition will be erased. Be sure to back up any data you want to keep before you begin.

1. Run the media creation tool.
2. Select Create installation media for another PC.
3. Choose the language, edition, and architecture (64-bit or 32-bit) for Windows 10.
4. Follow the steps to create the installation media, and then select Finish when it’s done.
5. When you’re ready to perform a clean installation, turn on your PC, insert the DVD or USB flash drive you created, and then shut down your PC.
6. Restart your PC, and then press any key to boot from the DVD or USB flash drive.

If you restart your PC and your current version of Windows starts, you might have to open a boot menu or change the boot order in your PC's BIOS or UEFI settings so that your PC boots from the media. To open a boot menu or change the boot order, you'll typically need to press a combination of keys (such as F2, F12, Delete, or Esc) immediately after you turn on your PC. For instructions on changing the boot order for your PC, check the documentation that came with your PC or go to the manufacturer's website.

If changing the boot menu or order doesn't work, try again by signing in to Windows, shutting down, and then starting your PC.

7. On the Install Windows page, enter your language and other preferences, and then select Next.
8. Select Install Windows.
9. On the Enter the product key to activate Windows page, click skip.

**Note**

Since you’ve already activated Windows 10 on this PC, you won't need to enter a Windows 10 product key. You can skip the product key page by selecting the Skip button. Your PC will automatically activate later.

10. On the License terms page, if you accept the license terms, select I accept the license terms, and then select Next.
11. On the "Which type of installation do you want?" page, select Custom. On the "Where do you want to install Windows?" page, select the partition that you want, select the formatting option you want to perform (if needed), and then follow the instructions.
12. When you've finished formatting, select Next.

Follow the rest of the setup instructions to finish installing Windows.

[Source](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10)

Hope this helps!

Comment: How do you know the OP is using a Surface tablet? Also, the OP stated "*BTW I have tried the reset your PC thing.. needless to say, it didn't work*". Can you address that?

Comment: Yes, I can. First off, these are instructions for Windows Operating systems. What kind of tablet it is will make very little (if any) difference. Secondly, the "reset your pc" thing has three options. I was stating which of the three should be selected. You can take a look at the articles, too @CharlieRB

Comment: Don't take this personal. I was not asking you to address me. Rather, explain in your answer why you are telling them to do what they said didn't work. I am glad you are answering this question and placing links there to the articles you have read. My comment was to illustrate that making assumptions can be misleading when trying to properly answer. That is why comments are used to get clarification from the OP prior to answering. Considering this in the future will make your answers that much better.

Comment: I apologize, I misunderstood you. I will update this answer like you said I should. But also, please keep in mind that a user must have 50 rep to comment for clarification :) The only way I know how to reach that ability, is to answer questions the best I can. @CharlieRB

Comment: @Ramhound What are you asking? I am merely giving instructions for reverting the OS

Comment: 2/3 of your answer is specific to Surface tablets.  I have no question, it's more shocked, your trying to justify this answer because your can't comment on questions

Comment: No, I'm not. I'm just replying as to why I didn't make a comment before I posted an answer. The instructions themselves are applicable to all Windows 10 tablets. Please tell me why you believe the tablet model is relevant to my specific answer. @Ramhound

Comment: Because you have steps to reset the tablet which are device specific?  Besides doing a reset would reset the professional version not install the home version.  I don't believe it's device specific actually but your answer is though

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34886/discussion-between-spencer4134-and-ramhound).

Comment: I have changed my answer as it was irrelevant @Ramhound

Comment: @Spencer4134  Why do you include information about the free upgrade?  His machine came with Windows 10, it has not relevance to his problem, what part of this answer exactly is your own words and what is from your link?  Material from another source should be quoted, cited, so its clearly disguisable from your own original words.  *This isn't the fist time in one of your answers where it was difficult to tell what you wrote and what somebody else wrote.*  Do yourself a favor, edit your question, so your original words and cited material is disguisable

Comment: I'm in the chat stated earlier. @Ramhound